# Record sounds using a two-dimensional array

Tags: iphone, multidimensional-array, audio-recording

i'd like to record sounds played by tapping with a two dimensional array using the time and the sound id.
is there any code example anywhere?
thanx blacksheep

Answer (score 0):

The code could look a bit like this:

```
@interface Recorder : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *times;
    NSMutableArray *samples;
}
@end

@implementation Recorder

- (id) init
{
    [super init];
    times = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    samples = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}

- (void) recordSound: (id) someSound
{
    CFAbsoluteTime now = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    NSNumber *wrappedTime = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:now];
    [times addObject:wrappedTime];
    [samples addObject:someSound];
}

@end
```

Now you’ll have the sample times in the `times` array and samples in the `samples` array. You could create a two-dimensional array to hold the data, but this looks easier.

Comment: thanx again - next step will be to save the recordings and play them again - eventually while playing new sonds.
i'll try to find out - if i don't succed, i'tell it here...

Comment: well, i must admit that i don't have any idea how to save and play again the recorded sounds...